# PIVOT operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

```
name      roll                  vote  total vote        status

aaa     Administrator             1    2            Feedback Received
aaa     HR Support Staff          1    2            Feedback Received
dev     Administrator             1    2            Shortlisted
dev     HR Support Staff          1    2            Shortlisted
raj     Administrator             1    1            Feedback Received
rajesh  HR Support Staff          2    2            Shortlisted
```

need to display like

```
Name     HR Support Staff       Administrator    Total Vote       Status

aaa            1                    1               2           Feedback Recived
```

how to display in this method?

Comment: How are you outputting the data?  Pivoting is much easier in the UI and/or reporting layer than in SQL.  Most grids and reporting tools support declarative, dynamic pivoting, while SQL reqiures static pivoting (or dynamic SQL which is hard to develop and debug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a `PIVOT` approach to this:

```
select [name], [Administrator], [HR Support Staff], [total vote], [status]
from Table1
pivot (
  min([vote])
  for [roll] in ([Administrator], [HR Support Staff])
) p
```

**[Working SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddb02/12)**

Comment: Just some thoughts for OP: Are there constraints on this table? If not, Min func can be replace with AVG and the column Vote to type DECIMAL. Also, should roll be role?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sparse on details here. You could use PIVOT or you could do a cross tab. If the values are static here is one way you could do this using a cross tab.

```
select name
    , SUM(case when roll = 'HR Support Staff' then 1 end) as HRSupportStaff
    , SUM(case when roll = 'Administrator' then 1 end) as Administrator
    , MAX(TotalVote) as TotalVote
    , Status
from YourTable
group by name, Status
```

Comment: values will be dynamic

Comment: OK. so you need to do a dynamic pivot or cross tab. If you look at google you will find tons of ways to do dynamic pivots and dynamic cross tabs.

Comment: Since you didn't provide anything to work with my code was just a guess. I couldn't test it. I left that part up to you.